# Combine different hierarchy levels using MDX Query

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, mdx-query

**1.Description**

Now I have two mdx query, the **only** differences is the ON ROWS settings.
Here is each query and its results.

Query 1 :

```
SELECT

NON EMPTY
{
  [PLOwner].[PLOwner].Members
}
ON ROWS
,
NON EMPTY
Crossjoin(
  {
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_RecoveryJTDTable],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Equivalent_Notional],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_SPC],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_PSM],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_PV10],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Notional],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Notional_IMM],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[PnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[TomorrowPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[RollPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[RollDownPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_JTD],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_Raw_KC],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_RR],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLWCOF],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLRR],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLSHW],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLBox],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLInterest]
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([Category].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([Label1].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([IsError].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
)
ON COLUMNS

FROM
  [UnityRiskCube]

WHERE
(
  [Measures].[Risk.SUM],
  [BusinessGroup].[BusinessGroup].[AeJ Flow Credit],
  [Context].[ContextId].[official:Live]
)
```

Result 1: (I use Excel to show String[][] result from Pivot)

[Result 1-click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWbc1.png)

Query 2 :

```
SELECT

NON EMPTY
Crossjoin(
  {
    [PLOwner].[PLOwner].Members
  }
  ,
  {
    [PLGroup].[PLGroup].Members
  }
)
ON ROWS
,
NON EMPTY
Crossjoin(
  {
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_RecoveryJTDTable],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Equivalent_Notional],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_SPC],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_PSM],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_PV10],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Notional],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Notional_IMM],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[PnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[TomorrowPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[RollPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[RollDownPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_JTD],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_Raw_KC],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_RR],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLWCOF],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLRR],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLSHW],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLBox],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLInterest]
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([Category].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([Label1].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([IsError].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
)
ON COLUMNS

FROM
  [UnityRiskCube]

WHERE
(
  [Measures].[Risk.SUM],
  [BusinessGroup].[BusinessGroup].[AeJ Flow Credit],
  [Context].[ContextId].[official:Live]
)
```

Result 2: (I use Excel to show String[][] result from Pivot)

[Result 2-click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnmI0.png)

**2.Question**

How can i get these data together using one Mdx query? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `ALL` member of the `PLGroup` hierarchy to be able to combine - you have no choice in that there will need to be the same dimensionality for both:

```
SELECT

NON EMPTY
{
  [PLOwner].[PLOwner].Members
 *[PLGroup].[PLGroup].[All] //<< or this may be [PLGroup].[All]
,
  [PLOwner].[PLOwner].Members
 *[PLGroup].[PLGroup].Members
}
ON ROWS
,
NON EMPTY
Crossjoin(
  {
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_RecoveryJTDTable],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Equivalent_Notional],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_SPC],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_PSM],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_PV10],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Notional],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Notional_IMM],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[PnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[TomorrowPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[RollPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[RollDownPnL],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_JTD],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_Raw_KC],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[Risk_RR],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLWCOF],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLRR],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLSHW],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLBox],
    [InfoType].[InfoType].[FundingPnLInterest]
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([Category].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([Label1].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
  ,
  {
    DrillDownLevel([IsError].[ALL].[AllMember])
  }
)
ON COLUMNS

FROM
  [UnityRiskCube]

WHERE
(
  [Measures].[Risk.SUM],
  [BusinessGroup].[BusinessGroup].[AeJ Flow Credit],
  [Context].[ContextId].[official:Live]
)
```

Comment: Million thanks!!! i use "[PLGroup].[All]" and results are quite similar with what i want. While i found that the result numbers still have problems, the sum of children is not equals father.  Anway, i will figure out it later. Thanks for your idea!!!